# Mapping of input and output values for a Multilayer Perceptron

Tags: regression, matlab

I try to understand Multilayer Perceptrons for function regression. As a starting reference I am using the matlab neuronal network toolbox. There I mentioned that the tool maps the input and output values to the range of [-1 1]. Why do they do this? I thought that the inputs need to be decorrelated and free of mean, but they don't do this.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674623/why-do-we-have-to-normalize-the-input-for-an-artificial-neural-network

Comment: Also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31641/do-inputs-to-a-neural-network-need-to-be-in-1-1

Comment: But the normalization regarding variance and mean has to be done before, right?