# Difference between NN weights/inputs/outputs from [0,1] and [-1,1]?

Tags: neural-networks, weights

[Here](http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/classes/mstc/nn/node2.html) I see NN inputs and outputs represented by a real number between 0 and 1. Yet, [elsewhere](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159943/i-would-like-to-know-exactly-why-nn-inputs-have-to-be-within-1-and-1?noredirect=1&lq=1) inputs are given between -1 and 1. I presume 0 or -1 acts like "inhibitory" and 1 acts like "excitatory". In which cases should I use one over the other? And does it make sense for some weights to be in one range and some in another?

Answer (score 0):

"Vanilla" neural networks (fully connected layers, trained via backpropagation) should converge to similar results because the linear part of the neural layer should adjust for scaling and bias. However I don't have a proof of this.

Also some activation functions have restricted outputs, like [0,1] for sigmoid and [-1,1] for tanh.